# PHP DomDocument's getElementsByTagName changing encoding

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding, domdocument

I'm trying to parse a XML and I am facing some problems  with PHP `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName` that I never had before.

This is my code to get the XML

```
$xmlToParse = new MXML('1,0','UTF-8');
$xmlToParse->loadXML(<myXML>);
//print_r ($xmlToParse->saveXML());die();
```

When I use the `print_r`, this is the result (part of):

```
<Hotel>
<HotelId>10333</HotelId>
<HotelName>Papillon Hotel</HotelName>
<Address>Avenida República do Líbano, 1824,Goiânia</Address>
<District>SETOR OESTE</District>
<City>Goiania</City>
<State>GO</State>
<Country>Brasil</Country>
<ZIP>74115 - 030</ZIP>
<Localization>Urbano com Atrativo</Localization>
<Category>Muito Confortável</Category>
<StarLevel>4</StarLevel>
<Descricao>O Papillon Hotel tem o orgulho e o prazer em servir bem, oferecendo aos hóspedes diversas opções em lazer, saúde e gourmet. O café da manhã é servido de segunda a sexta-feira, entre 6hs e 10hs, com acesso pelo elevador "R". Aos sábados, domingos e feriados, para seu maior conforto, o serviço se entende das 06hs às 11hs. O Papillon Hotel conta com restaurante de padrão internacional, com opções de pratos à la carte ou buffet executivo, em um agradável ambiente com vista panorâmica da cidade. E aos sábados, você ainda encontra a melhor feijoada da cidade. No lobby do hotel, um sofisticado e aconchegante Café Bistrô convida os hóspedes e não-hóspedes a desfrutarem de um mix variado de saladas, risotos, sanduíches e massas de sabor requintado, além de deliciosas sobremesas e cafés expresso e gelado E na cobertura o único SPA da cidade com toda estrutura de alto padrão em um hotel. Você encontra um completo complexo de lazer e Spa, o primeiro e único Spa do Centro-Oeste com toda a estrutura de um hotel do mais alto padrão. Desfrute de piscina, duchas, saunas seca e a vapor, salas de ginástica e musculação e sala de massagem e beleza. E, de presente, leve uma vista panorâmica de Goiânia. Dispostos nas categorias standard, luxo, suí­te e suí­te presidencial , os apartamentos do Papillon Hotel se destacam pelo bom gosto, requinte, decoração e excelência em produtos e serviços prestados. Nos apartamentos do Papillon Hotel, você vai encontrar: ar condicionado central, telefones com discagem direta, som ambiente, TV a cabo, frigobar, entrada para computador, serviço de despertador e room-service.     </Descricao>
<HorarioCheckin>14:00</HorarioCheckin>
```

Everything apparently okay. The next step is get the tag values, so that is my code for get Address:

```
$hotelTag = $hotelDetailResponseTag->getElementsByTagName('Hotel')->item(0);
$addressTagValue = $hotelTag->getElementsByTagName('Address')->item(0)->nodeValue;
//print_r ($addressTagValue);die();
```

When I use the `print_r`, that is the result (the same occurs with all other tags)

> Avenida RepÃºblica do LÃ­bano, 1824,GoiÃ¢nia

Why this is happening? The `getElementsByTagName` is changing the encoding of the XML? How to fix it?

FYI: 1) My final objective is save these informations in a database, already with utf8 enconding. 
2) When i use `mb_detect_encoding($xmlToParse->saveXML())` the result is "UTF-8".

Comment: That's not PHP. that's your display environment having the wrong character set. e.g. you're taking your utf8 xml and spitting it out into an iso8859 web browser.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB I'm printing in the console, but I think that is not the problem, because when I debug my code and breakpoint my $addressTagValue var I still get the problem in the IDE viewer and when I save the information in database (utf8) the problem also persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a workaround to this problem.

I bet that isn't the better way, but worked for me for now. Just complete the loadXML with this code:

```
$xmlToParse->loadXML(mb_convert_encoding($strHotelDetailResult->textContent,'UTF-8',mb_detect_encoding($strHotelDetailResult->textContent)));
```